# data binding not working in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

**Issue:** while deleting the 1st row, and adding the 2nd row, the value of 1st row gets replaced by 2nd row's value.

I have created a plunker for the issue i am facing https://next.plnkr.co/edit/1FL8qmSgMsSQCGNT?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&preview

Steps to reproduce:

1. click on 'Select One' drop-down and select 'Screen 1' option.
2. Again click on 'Select One' drop-down and select 'Screen 2' option.
3. Now delete 1st row (Screen 1).
4. Again click on 'Select One' drop-down and select 'Screen 3' option.

The 1st row's value gets replaced by the 2nd row's value.

I dont know whats wrong in my code which is causing this issue .

Comment: If you display the index and the array ou will get a better view of what is happening : https://next.plnkr.co/edit/EqObXPMMmUjxuG89?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&preview

Comment: Add more options, like 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4 and then change the generated values of 2 or something. They are influencing each other. Maybe go with a approach where you don't modify the list itself, but generating new lists.. would be easier in my opinion.

Comment: @ibenjelloun Yes, you are right... I also did this. The array is correct after delete and after add but why value gets changed? where is the problem?

Comment: @ Stefan Rein, But what is the issue in this current code ?

Answer (score 2):

You have main issue is that you have used ngModel for select element.

So when you select item from select element at that time value is changed in selectedIds[rowIndex] item.

I have applied minor code refactoring in first div as per below it will helpful to you.

```
<div *ngFor="let id of selectedIds; let rowIndex = index">
    <select name="id_{{rowIndex}}" class="form-control" required >
        <option *ngFor="let screen of screens"
        [selected]="screen.screenId==id"
         [ngValue]="screen.screenId">{{screen.screenName}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <a class="pointer" (click)="removeScreen(rowIndex)">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working on UI, but the binding is not working because you have removed the ngModel...Now the issue is as per your suggestion, how binding will work in this solution ?

Comment: For that you need to create separate property for binding like you need to create custom object list in place number array(selectedIds). Do you want me to create sample ?

Comment: You did a lot for me to resolve this issue. It would be great thanks to you if you can create a sample for the same. Sory for the inconvenience :)

Answer (score 1):

it's late but the problem is this code that exists in Metronic Template:
`changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,`
and you should comment this line of code to enable data binding.